# Sum values of JSON array in oracle sql

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a Table which contains data like id, country, city,capacity. Capacity is a JSON array field which has values like
[{'totalCapacity':100.0},{'totalCapacity':90.0},{'totalCapacity':80.0},{'totalCapacity':80.0}] against a row in table, so row in table looks like

| id | country | city | capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | new-york | [{'totalCapacity':100.0},{'totalCapacity':90.0},{'totalCapacity':80.0},{'totalCapacity':80.0}] |

Now I want result as

| id | country | city | sum(capacity) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | new-york | 350 |

i.e sum of totalCapacity against each row.

Tried this

```
SELECT
    id,
    country,
    city,
    SUM(JSON_VALUE(capacity, '$.totalCapacity')) AS total_capacity
FROM
    A 
GROUP BY
    id,
    country,
    city;
```

but getting nulls in total_capacity

Comment: Your JSON is invalid as the object keys should be quoted using double quotes and not single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` a `JSON_TABLE` and aggregate in that:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       t.country,
       t.city,
       j.totalCapacity
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT SUM(totalCapacity) AS totalCapacity
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.capacity,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    totalcapacity NUMBER PATH '$.totalCapacity'
                  )
                )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id       NUMBER,
  country  VARCHAR2(50),
  city     VARCHAR2(50),
  capacity CLOB CHECK (capacity IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (
  id,
  country,
  city,
  capacity
) VALUES (
  1,
  'usa',
  'new-york',
  '[{"totalCapacity":100.0},{"totalCapacity":90.0},{"totalCapacity":80.0},{"totalCapacity":80.0}]'
);
```

Outputs:

| ID | COUNTRY | CITY | TOTALCAPACITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | new-york | 350 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mRPK_rb4)

Answer (score 1):

From 21, you can also use sum() item function directly in json_value:

```
with data(js) as (
    select '[{"totalCapacity":100.0},{"totalCapacity":90.0},{"totalCapacity":80.0},{"totalCapacity":80.0}]' from dual
)
select json_value(js, '$[*].totalCapacity.sum()')
as val
from data
;

val
350
```

Comment: what is js over here?

Comment: I want to do it with json_value without with clause.How can I achieve that?

Comment: Seriously ??? You replace "from data" by "from your_table" and "js" by the name of the column containing the JSON...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id,
    country,
    city,
    SUM(j.totalCapacity) AS total_capacity
FROM
    A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(capacity) WITH (totalCapacity FLOAT '$.totalCapacity') AS j
GROUP BY
    id,
    country,
    city;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: OPENJSON is MSSQL syntax not ORACLE.